# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i)[zI -> zI -> zI]: NullInjectorError: No provider for zI

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I am upgrading Apollo to the first version, and I have this error:
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i)[zI -> zI -> zI]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for zI!

I tried to add the new version with the documentation and with yarn:
https://the-guild.dev/graphql/apollo-angular/docs/get-started

Comment: Please run you app in development mode, it's impossible to help with the symbols removed in prod build.

Comment: @Matthieu Riegler My application is actually in development mode but its does not works. but i have new error still incomprehensible: 
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[a1 -> a1]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for a1!

Here is my config fir dev mode:
'dev": {
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"fileReplacements": [
{
 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
}]},'

Comment: `optimization` should be false to be in devMode. Having it at true enables the mangling (minification of your symbols).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is run your app in development mode, thanks at @Matthieu Riegler for your help is works !!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).